# {"error":"invalid_token","error_description":""} (Podbean api)

Tags: django

I am trying to use Podbean api in my Django application. As per the document provided, I am authenticating my app. I have followed all the steps but when I try to run the following code in terminal I get error:

```
curl -u username:password \
 https://api.podbean.com/v1/oauth/debugToken \
  -G -d 'access_token=t4dfcgf7eb2ba65a289a6e8a8993cb9785e877y4'
```

Error:

```
{"error":"invalid_token","error_description":""}
```

I have checked all my credentials and they are correct. What is the problem here?

Comment: Obviously you are supplying an invalid token. Make sure you are getting and sending a valid token.

Comment: I have tried like 20 times. Being very precise about the token. I am sure that I am sending a valid token.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found out the mistake:

> client_id = App ID
>
> client_secert = App Secret

I was writing 'username' and 'password' for 'client_id' and 'client_secret'

Comment: Does one have to login to access the podbean api? You can't hit the podcast api without logging in?